# CFInput autosuggest: where is the value?

Tags: ajax, coldfusion, autosuggest

I used a simple CFInput autosuggest code (copied from [Ben Forta's blog](http://www.forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2007/5/31/ColdFusion-Ajax-Tutorial-1-AutoSuggest)). It works ok, but I need one additional feature:

After a user has used the autosuggest field to choose something, I would like to populate a second form field with the result ... but it doesn't work like in Javascript (using onChange and the value property of the field) - it seems that the "value" property contains the original user input, not what he chooses from the autosuggest list. For the life of it I can't find out how to copy the chosen autosuggest value to another field using Javascript. Anyone?

Comment: There is no need for shortened URLs here. Please use the full URL: http://www.forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2007/5/31/ColdFusion-Ajax-Tutorial-1-AutoSuggest

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your code?  My guess is you want the second `cfinput` to be similar to line with `*`'s:

```
<cfform>
Art:
<cfinput type="text"
        name="artname"
        autosuggest="cfc:art.lookupArt({cfautosuggestvalue})">
**<cfinput type="text" name="second" bind="{artname}"/>**
</cfform>
```